# jQuery plugin not working for multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, plugins

```js
(function ( $ ) {
 $.fn.bcatUpload = function (options) {
  if ( methods[options] ) {
   return methods[ options ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
  } else if ( typeof options === 'object' || ! options ) {
   return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
  } else {
   $.error( 'Method ' +  options + ' does not exist on jQuery.bcatUpload' );
  }
 }

 $.fn.bcatUpload.files_array = [];


 var methods = {
  init: function (arguments) {
   return this.each(function(index, el) {

    element = $(this);
    var settings = $.extend(true, {}, $defaults, arguments);
    private_methods.prepare(element);

    element.change(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var file_list = element[0].files;
     $.each(file_list, function(index, file) {
      $.fn.bcatUpload.files_array.push(file);
      private_methods.display(element);
     });
    });
   });
  },
  remove: function (index) {
   element = $(this);
   $.fn.bcatUpload.files_array.splice(index, 1);
   console.log($.fn.bcatUpload.files_array);
   private_methods.display(element);
  },
  upload: function () {
   // Start the upload...
   console.log('Uploading...');
   console.log($.fn.bcatUpload.files_array);
   return methods;
  }
 };

 var private_methods = {
  prepare: function (element) {
   $html = element.wrap('<div class="bcat-upload-container"></div>').parent();
   element.hide();
   var btn_class= ($defaults.button.class == null) ? '' : 'class="'+$defaults.button.class+'"';
   $html.append('<button type="button" '+btn_class+'>'+$defaults.button.label+'</button>');
   $html.append('<div class="bcat-file-list"></div><div class="bcat-clear"></div>');
   $html.find('button').click(function(event) {
    element.click();
   });
  },
  display: function (element) {
   $html = element.siblings('.bcat-file-list');
   var file_string = '';
   $.each($.fn.bcatUpload.files_array, function(index, file) {
    file_name = private_methods.formatFileName(file);
    file_string += '<blockquote><span class="filename">'+file_name+'</span>';
    file_string += '<a class="close" href="javascript:$('+element.attr('id')+').bcatUpload(\'remove\', '+index+');" data-index="'+index+'">';
    file_string += '&times;</a></blockquote>';
   });
   $html.html(file_string);

   // Register the Click Event Handler.
   // $html.find('blockquote a.close').click(function(event) {
   //  methods.remove($(this).attr('data-index'));
   // });
  },
  formatFileName: function (file) {
   var filename = private_methods.getFileName(file.name);
   var ext = private_methods.getExtension(file.name);
   if (filename.length > 20) {
    filename = filename.substring(0, 20) + '..';
   }
   return filename + '.' + ext;
  },
  getExtension: function (filename) {
   var file_name_array = filename.split('.');
    return file_name_array[file_name_array.length - 1];
  },
  getFileName: function (filename) {
   var file_name_array = filename.split('.');
   var ext = private_methods.getExtension(filename);
   return filename.substring(0, filename.length - parseInt(ext.length) - 1);
  },
  getHumanSize: function (bytes, si) {
   var thresh = si ? 1000 : 1024;
      if(Math.abs(bytes) < thresh) {
          return bytes + ' B';
      }
      var units = si
          ? ['KB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB']
          : ['KiB','MiB','GiB','TiB','PiB','EiB','ZiB','YiB'];
      var u = -1;
      do {
          bytes /= thresh;
          ++u;
      } while(Math.abs(bytes) >= thresh && u < units.length - 1);
      return bytes.toFixed(1)+' '+units[u];
  }
 }

 var $defaults = {
  id    : $(this).attr('id'),
  url   : '',
  data   : {},
  type   : 'image',
  size   : {
   min  : null,     // 1024  => 1KB.
   max  : null,     // 2097152  => 2MB.
   total  : null,     // 4194304  => 4MB.
  },
  dimention  : {
   min  : [null, null],
   max  : [null, null]
  },
  allowed   : {
   ext  : [],
   mimes  : {
    image : [
     'image/jpeg',    // JPG/JPEG image.
     'image/gif',    // GIF   image.
     'image/png',    // PNG   image.
     'image/bmp'    // BMP   Image
    ], 
    file: [
     'application/pdf',                // PDF  file.
     'application/msword',               // DOC  file.
     'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'  // DOCX file.
    ]
   }
  },
  button   : {
   class  : null,
   label  : 'Select File',
   icon  : null
  },
  limit   : 0
 }
}( jQuery ));

$(":file").bcatUpload({
 size: {
  min: 2048,
  max: 50000000 
 }
});
```

```css
div.bcat-upload-container {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
 }
 div.bcat-upload-container button, #upload {
  background: darkred;
  padding:10px 15px;
  border-width: 0px;
  color:#F2F2F2;
  font-weight:bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
 }
 div.bcat-upload-container .bcat-clear {clear: both;}
 div.bcat-upload-container div.bcat-file-list {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
 }
 div.bcat-upload-container div.bcat-file-list blockquote {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
 div.bcat-upload-container div.bcat-file-list blockquote .filename {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
 }
 div.bcat-upload-container div.bcat-file-list blockquote a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
 }

    #upload {background: darkgreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="file" id="docs1" multiple /><br />
  <input type="file" id="docs2" multiple /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Upload" id="upload" onclick="$(':file').bcatUpload('upload');" />
</form>
```

Above is the plugin for file upload. The above code works when there is only one file element selected. But if I select multiple then it stops working correctly. It only works for the last one that I instantiate.

I can't figure out what went wrong.

Note: The file upload process through ajax is not included here... I just wan't to have the selected files array set up for each of the file elements I have in the html. Then I can commence the upload method to execute the ajax file upload.